# GetComputedStyle to other media than screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
@media screen{    
    a {color:green}
}

@media print{
    a {color:red}
}
```

Is there a way, using JavaScript, to get the color of the "A" element when it's printed?
The normal `getComputedStyle` works only for `screen` media.

I don't want to read the style element. I need the computed style.

Comment: Maybe, there is a way to simulate print media on the screen. Then we can use GetComputedStyle...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I develop a solution how to remove all the styles of the PRINT media.
This way the print style will be the same like SCREEN style.

This is make the printer print exactly like it's appear on the screen.

```
console.debug('styleSheetsLength')
                $('link[media=print]').remove()
                $('link[media*=screen]').attr('media','print,screen')
                for (var x=0; x<document.styleSheets.length;x++){
                    console.groupCollapsed('styleSheet-' + x,document.styleSheets[x])
                    if(document.styleSheets[x].rules){
                        for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets[x].rules.length;i++) {
                            console.groupCollapsed('rule-(' + x + ')-' +i +  document.styleSheets[x].rules[i])
                            console.debug(document.styleSheets[x].rules[i])
                            if(document.styleSheets[x].rules[i].media){
                                for(var j=0;j<document.styleSheets[x].rules[i].media.length;j++){
                                    if (document.styleSheets[x].rules[i].media[j].indexOf('print')>-1)
                                        document.styleSheets[x].rules[i].media.mediaText='nothing'
                                    if (document.styleSheets[x].rules[i].media[j].indexOf('screen')>-1)
                                        document.styleSheets[x].rules[i].media.mediaText='print,screen'
                                }
                            }
                            console.groupEnd();
                        }
                    }
                    console.groupEnd()
                }
```

Comment: Please, dereference those member operator monsters! Not only to speed your script up, but to make it readable.

Comment: Wasn't your goal to *get* the print styles, not to *remove* them? You just could have applied them by transforming them into screen styles.

Comment: Now, you can continue to "getComputedStyle", and then restore the CSS back to the original.